# Is there a Sublime Text 2 package that supports literate Haskell files (.lhs)?

Tags: sublimetext2

I found packages that give me syntax highlighting on Haskell files (.hs) but not literate Haskell files (.lhs).

Answer (score 4):

Adding bird style is quite easy, just edit your `Literate Haskell.tmLanguage` to add the following:

```
<!-- ... -->
<string>Literate Haskell</string>
<key>patterns</key>
<array>
      <!-- Start here -->
      <dict>
            <key>begin</key>
            <string>^&gt;</string>
            <key>end</key>
            <string>$</string>
            <key>patterns</key>
            <array>
                  <dict>
                        <key>include</key>
                        <string>source.haskell</string>
                  </dict>
            </array>
      </dict>
<!-- ... -->
```

This is simply a regex saying "starting from > to newline is source". I'm not sure how robust this is (dollar signs tend to misbehave iirc), but I guess it's a hint in the right direction.

Comment: It would be nice with a bit more information, like where to find the file; if I should append to it or create a new one; and if I need to reload it somehow/delete cache files etc.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to low rep.

Basing my efforts largely on David's answer, I made a custom .tmLanguge file for Bird Style, and uploaded it to my [bitbucket.](https://bitbucket.org/wrossmck/literate-haskell-bird-style)

To install, just download the .tmLanguage file provided, and move it into your packages folder.

On OSX it's located at `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Haskell/`

You can access your packages location by going to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`

Comment: this is a very old question. Its recommended not to put answer on outdated questions, check next time when it was posted. Good answer though! Now go get some reputation points :)

Comment: Ahh, right! I hadn't noticed the time. Was just trying to get bird style working, and then saw that other comment that David's answer was incomplete.

Comment: Can you add your package to sublime package control?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I have no idea how to do that, but i can look into it!

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I've submitted it to be included with SublimeHaskell, so it will eventually be part of their package

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.0.1, literate Haskell is supported, but only the tex and not the bird style.